# Please accept all necessary Android SDK licenses

Tags: android, react-native, windows-10

Setting up a React Native development environment on Windows for the first time, I create a new React Native project, cd into it, and run `react-native run-android`. I receive the error:

> info Starting JS server... The system cannot find the path specified.
> info Launching emulator... error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No
> emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.  warn Please
> launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may
> fail to launch.
>
> error Failed to install the app. Please accept all necessary Android
> SDK licenses using Android SDK Manager:
> "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses". Run CLI with
> --verbose flag for more details. Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

I've tried:

- Go to Configure>SDK Manager in your Android Studio. Select SDK Tools tab and install Google Play Licensing Library
- Open Android Studio, then click the gear icon (Configure). Press the SDK Manager option. Three tabs should be displayed, press the SDK Tools tab. After that, make sure that Android SDK Build-Tools, Android SDK Platform-Tools and Android SDK Tools are updated. Check them and press Apply.
- Installing v28 of Android SDK and opened a Pixel 2 VD running v28.
- Run Powershell C:\users\steve\appdata\local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin> ./sdkmanager.bat --licenses. I receive the error:

> Warning: File C:\Users\steve\ .android\repositories.cfg could not be
> loaded. All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing
> updates...

I've created a blank C:\Users\steve\ .android\repositories.cfg file, and started an Android emulator through Android Studio, but receive the same error.

Comment: You have to only do as it's asking you to. Open command prompt and type ``$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`` and hit enter.

Comment: @OMiShah I've done that already, it's in the question.

Comment: Okay, can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57124607/react-native-failed-to-install-the-app-please-accept-all-necessary-sdk-licens and see if any answer works for you.

Comment: @OMiShah: tried all of those answers and the error remains, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

- Install latest JDK -- [installation link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_manual_download.xml)
- export JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME environment variables  [setup link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must)

if you are windows machine run following command

```
cmd.exe /C"%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses"
```

if you are macOS run following command

```
yes | sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept the licenses through the terminal/prompt:

**1. on Windows:**

```
$ cd /d "%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%/tools/bin"
$ sdkmanager --licenses
```

**2. on linux:**

```
$ cd Android/sdk/tools/bin/
$ ./sdkmanager --licenses
```